# Truncating a value before a decimal in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

I am moving a data from oracle table to the Postgres using with help of dblink, and in the new table structure of the Postgres I have added precision to the numeric column which were without precision in Oracle, now while moving the data I am able to truncate the decimal values to match the scale, however, I am struggling to find a way to truncate a value before the decimal point if it does not match the precision.

to adjust the scale I am using the below command:

```
insert into Postgres.test 
select id, width::numeric(7,3) 
from oracle.test;
```

So, in this case, if the value after the decimal is greater than 3 digits it will truncate it to the 3 digits, however, I want if the precision (before the decimal) is greater than 4 than it should also get truncated to the 4 digits, I don't mind if the value of few rows gets changed by doing so.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. If the original value is e.g. `12345.678` what should be the result of that operation?

Comment: in this case, if the value is 12345.678 so I want it to be 1234.567 or 1234.678 both values are fine for me

Comment: That makes no sense whatsover to me. I agree with Laurenz that settings those values to `null` makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can “left truncate” the number before the decimal point with

```
insert into Postgres.test 
select id, (width % 10000)::numeric(7,3) 
from oracle.test;
```

But I don't see much point in doing that. It might be better to use a NULL than a bad value:

```
insert into Postgres.test 
select id, CASE WHEN width >= 10000 THEN NULL ELSE width::numeric(7,3) END
from oracle.test;
```